# Get primary key of a deserialized object in Django

Tags: python, json, django

I have a list of objects stored in session (to pass the list from one view to another) [okay, there has to be a better way of doing this but this is a question for another time!]

I access the list from the session by doing:

```
object_list = request.session.get('object_list', None)
```

But this object_list is actually a serialized django object.

What i need is to now get all the pk of this object_list (to then rebuild a clean queryset...)

I tried this (deserializing then getting pk)

```
object_list_id=[]
for obj in serializers.deserialize("json", object_list):
            object_list_id.append(obj.pk)
```

but it doesn't seem to work.. any ideas ?

```
'DeserializedObject' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

PS: if i debug the obj from the loop, this is the object type:

```
{<DeserializedObject: riskass.Rating(pk=7)>}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got it, it doesn't say anything on this aspect in the documentation !

**How to get the pk of a serialized object in django:**

```
# filtered_ratings : list of serialized objects (serialized through django's serializer)

from django.core import serializers

for obj in serializers.deserialize("json", filtered_ratings):
    pk = obj.object.pk
```

Hope this helps someone someday !